# Навигационное меню Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Уважаемые разработчики! 
Подскажите, как средствами laravel 5.4 сделать связь один-ко-многим в **ОДНОЙ** таблице. Хочу вывести меню с неограниченной вложенностью. Есть таблица catalogs ('id','title','parent'),где parent - id родителя В документации читал про hasMany с двумя таблицами, пытался так же сделать с одной - не вышло.Понравилось решение по этой ссылке: https://www.sitepoint.com/laravel-blade-recursive-partials/
но не знаю как данные привести в данную структуру, чтобы был массив по полю childrens, например.
Возможно тут есть решение, как на C# entity framework code first, там я указывал тип данных просто 
и фреймворк автоматически создавал связь.
Еще вопрос, если кто знает: а если я руками в phpmyadmin сделаю связь один-ко-многим, в laravel уже не надо прописывать hasMany?

В laravel новичок, буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: hasMany к self прописать. А для работы с деревьями посмотрите в сторону nested set - если большие деревья очень удобно. Пакет для ларавер baum называется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28930251/2674819

Comment: в Laravel надо прописать связи.
без этого Eloquent не будет видеть связь

Comment: Это двумя словами новичку не скажешь. но посмотри здесь!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN15LtMy38I